# Applying gravity to objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm having trouble with implementing gravity on objects.

I have a bunch of circle objects that I'm drawing using OpenGL. I'm using `delta-x` and `delta-y` to move the circles (balls). I'm trying to add a gravitational constant to the `y` coordinate each frame so it simulates being pulled downward, but I'm not  sure exactly how to do that.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class Ball
{
    public:
        double x;
        double y;
        double radius;
        double deltaX;
        double deltaY;
};


std::vector<Ball> gAllBalls;  // a vector of balls with random positions and delta-values
double gGravity = ?;  // gravitational constant - I know it's 92 m/s^s, but I don't know how to apply that to deltaX and deltaY


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (auto &thisBall : gAllBalls)
    {
        // draw
        glColor3d(thisBall.red, thisBall.green, thisBall.blue);
        DrawCircle(thisBall.x, thisBall.y, thisBall.radius);

        // gravity - not working
        if (thisBall.y + thisBall.radius < gScreenHeight - gGravity)
        {
            thisBall.y += gGravity;
        }

        // wall bouncing
        if (thisBall.y + thisBall.radius + thisBall.deltaY >= gScreenHeight)  // up
        {
            thisBall.deltaY = -thisBall.deltaY;
        }

        if (thisBall.y + thisBall.deltaY - thisBall.radius < 0)  // down
        {
            thisBall.deltaY = -thisBall.deltaY;
        }

        if (thisBall.x + thisBall.deltaX - thisBall.radius < 0) // left
        {
            thisBall.deltaX = -thisBall.deltaX;
        }

        if (thisBall.x + thisBall.radius + thisBall.deltaX >= gScreenWidth)  // right
        {
            thisBall.deltaX = -thisBall.deltaX;
        }

        // move
        thisBall.x += thisBall.deltaX;
        thisBall.y += thisBall.deltaY;
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

A big problem I'm having is that I don't know how to calculate the gravity, since I'm using `deltaX` and `deltaY` instead of having separate speed and distance variables to calculate 92 m/s^2. However, no matter what I set the gravity to, the balls don't behave like they should - regardless of gravity strength, so there has to be something else wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: `thisBall.y += gGravity;`   This will result in constant velocity, not constant acceleration.  If you adjust deltaY rather than Y, you'll probably get closer to what you intend.  Best would be to work in engineering units such as meters and seconds rather than pixels and arbitrary time steps, then convert between them as needed.   Finally, your value for 'G' is off, it's really 9.8 m/sec^2

Comment: Ah, of course that makes more sense. I changed it to deltaY instead of Y and it initially seems to work, but the balls begin to accelerate faster and faster instead of slowing down. I'm just using 1 as the gravity constant.

I'd love to use better units, but I'm not to sure how to implement them. Do you have any suggestions or resources?

Comment: "**92** m/s^2", where are you simulating, some sort of ultra-Jupiter or a small star?

Comment: What application is this for? If you're trying to simulate real motion in a uniform gravitational field, you would use the equations y_{t} = y_{t-dt} + v_{y,t-dt}dt - 0.5gdt^{2}. y_{t} is the position at time t, dt is the time between calls to `display()`, v_{y,t-dt} is the velocity at the previous time step (last time you called `display()`), and g is the magnitude of the gravitational acceleration (9.8m/s^{2}) on Earth.

Comment: @Grav by the way, there's no real reason to use 9.8 m/s^2 unless you're trying to do a realistic simulation of motion on Earth. The equations I posted above will still give you the correct type of motion, and you can change g to whatever you find looks nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is the physics, rather than the programming technique.
In your case, I would change the 'delta' members of your Ball class to 'speed', since they are a unit of distance that change the position of your object per cycle (time), however this is just a suggestion to make it easier to visualize...

```
class Ball
{
    public:
        double x;
        double y;
        double radius;
        double speedX;
        double speedY;
};
```

In second place, I in your code, you are changing the 'y' member, rather than the speed, and since gravity changes speed, hence the problem.
Try doing that, and for debugging purposes, I would try with punctual objects (no radius, just plain (x,y) coordinates).

So, to conclude, I would simply change your gravity code to the following:

```
  // gravity - 'fixed'
  if (thisBall.y + thisBall.radius < gScreenHeight - gGravity)
  {
      thisBall.speedY -= gGravity; //notice the '-'
  }
```

The value of gravity should be absolute and positive, so as to keep things as simple as posible. If you try this, you should have an ideal simple physics simulator, with a ball of constant speedX (only changing its direction, not magnitude).
Please try this, and let me know how it went, good luck, keep it up =)

Comment: As a physicist that `speedY -= gGravity;` looks weird to me. It'd make `gGravity` itself a negative number and positively sum it (`+=`).

Comment: Thank you! That got me much closer to the desired result. However, I'm still having a small issue: when the balls bounce, they bounce higher and higher each bounce instead of slowing down and eventually settling on the bottom. The only thing I changed was gravity affecting speed instead of position. Would you have any suggestions why this would be  happening?

Comment: I think I had a similar issue. When the ball bounces, I was flipping the negative value of dx and dy. This worked for slanted surfaces. I fixed it by only flipping them on slanted surfaces, and negating them on flat surfaces.